# No sound for builtin speakers after i connected an external sound card?

Tags: microphone, soundcard, external-soundcard

I can still see builtin speaker in the menu but when i chose it there is no output sound. You can see my sound settings here:

[image: Sound settings screenshot]

The problem started after i connected an external sound card called ugreen that i recently purchased from amazon. I wanted to connect an external mic therefore i used it. It worked fine and perfectly. But now when i removed it. The builtin speaker of laptop has no sound.

### Hardware specs

- sound card : [product link](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B016CU2PEU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- Laptop: Acer Nitro5
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Please help in this regards, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved by help from this article: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

When a mixer control is muted, “MM” appears below the volume bar. Note that a bar can be 100% full but still be muted, so do check for this. You can unmute a control by pressing the m key. This changes “MM” to “OO.”